# how to reload the same page while click delete button in php - moodle

Tags: php, moodle

I want to reload the same page while i am clicking delete button. The delete button action is working but the page is not reloaded. how to solve this issues.

I am trying the following code :

```
 if($delete){

    $del = delete_records('mastercourse',$field='id',$value=$delete);
   location.reload();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are embedding javascript inside PHP, so enclose with  tags

```
echo "<script>location.reload()</script>";
```

or if you want to redirect: (from discussion)

```
echo "<script>location.href='viewfile.php'</script>";
```

alternatively, can use PHP's

```
header("Refresh:0");
```

Comment: If i am trying like this means the page is reloading again and again how to solve this error

Comment: Whenever if condition `$delete` is true, it executes the code

Comment: ya if i delete one record means it was deleted but the page is reloading again and again

Comment: reset the `$delete` to false, may be inside the if condition

Comment: update with the current code and the code which triggers $delete

Comment: if($delete){
             
        $del = delete_records('mastercourse',$field='id',$value=$delete);
       
        $delete='false';
        echo "<script>location.reload()</script>";
        
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94275/discussion-between-nisanth-and-vijaya-sankar-n).

Comment: The solution that uses the 'redirect()' function is much better if you are working within Moodle.

Answer (score 1):

Just add Redirect() like below :

```
if($delete){

$del = delete_records('mastercourse',$field='id',$value=$delete);

redirect($CFG->wwwroot."/viewfile.php");

}
```

Here viewfile.php is the file name to redirect.